# Polyline and Overlay bearing features together

Tags: google-maps, react-native-maps

I'm using `react-native-maps` and I need to use the Polyline feature and the Overlay component's bearing option together. But so far I couldn't find a library version with the both features. I have tried some versions of the library,

**version 0.27.1**

✅ Can show the root path using the Polyline

❌ Cannot rotate the Overlay using the bearing prop

---

**Versions 0.28.0 and 0.29.0**

✅ Can rotate the Overlay using the bearing prop

❌ It throws an error when using Polyline. (Throws this [error](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3823#issue-893926728))

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `react-native-maps@0.29.0`.

And setting the `lineDashPattern` as below,

```
<Polyline
  ...
  lineDashPattern={[1]}
/>
```

Now both `Polyline` and *bearing* in `Overlay` are working fine together